# Convert list in python to string

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list like this:

```py
my_list = ['Food']
```

What I need is to convert it to a string like this:

```py
"["food"]"
```

**Update:**

I am trying to save in csv file but it gives me an empty string.

Code:

```py
with open("food.csv", "x", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    wr = csv.writer(file)
    wr.writerow(["Food", "Id",])
    wr.writerow(str(my_list))
    wr.writerow('1')
```

**Last update:**
Solved!
I just needed to do the following:

```py
with open("languages_books.csv", "x", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    wr = csv.writer(file)
    wr.writerow(["Food", "Id",)

    wr.writerows([ [[my_list]], ['Id'] ])
```

Comment: `str(my_list)`.

Comment: `str(my_list)`?

Comment: `str(my_list)`!

Comment: `f'"{str(my_list)}"'`

Comment: What, *exactly*, are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

**Last update:**
Solved!
I just needed to do the following:

```py
with open("languages_books.csv", "x", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    wr = csv.writer(file)
    wr.writerow(["Food", "Id",)

    wr.writerows([ [[my_list]], ['Id'] ])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just use the str function

```
ans = str(my_list)
```